# Remove white space

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the white space in the filename that I have created using the follwing code:

```
epoch <- strsplit(toString(files[val]),split='.', fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]
    print(paste(epoch,".csv"))
```

The current output gives me: `"2016_Q3 .csv"`. I would like to remove the whitespace between the `3` and the `.`so the final string looks like `"2016_Q3.csv"`

I have looked at `gsub` and `trimws`, but can't get them to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paste` puts a space by default.
Instead do:

```
paste(epoch,".csv",sep="")
```

or

```
paste0(epoch,".csv")
```

Both return:

```
[1] "2016_Q3.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `gsub` it becomes a pretty simple task.

```
str <- "2016_Q3 .csv"
gsub(" ","",str)
```

Gives you:

```
"2016_Q3.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by a dot (`\\.` - escape the dot as it is a metacharacter implying any character) and replace it with `.`

```
sub("\\s+\\.", ".", str1)
#[1] "2016_Q3.csv"
```

Using the OP's example, even a non-specific (`\\s+`) should work

```
sub("\\s+", "", str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2016_Q3 .csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
epoch = str_replace(epoch, " ", "")
```